# Bijection - Java Avro Serialization

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, avro, bijection

I am looking for an example to do Bijection on Avro `SpecificRecordBase` object similar to a `GenericRecordBase` or if there is a simpler way to use the `AvroSerializer` class as the Kafka key and value serializer.

```
Injection<GenericRecord, byte[]> genericRecordInjection =
                                        GenericAvroCodecs.toBinary(schema);
byte[] bytes = genericRecordInjection.apply(type);
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/miguno/kafka-storm-starter provides such example code.

See, for instance, [AvroDecoderBolt](https://github.com/miguno/kafka-storm-starter/blob/develop/src/main/scala/com/miguno/kafkastorm/storm/bolts/AvroDecoderBolt.scala).  From its javadocs:

> This bolt expects incoming data in Avro-encoded binary format, serialized according to the Avro schema of `T`.  It will deserialize the incoming data into a `T` pojo, and emit this pojo to downstream consumers.  As such this bolt can be considered the Storm equivalent of Twitter Bijection's `Injection.invert[T, Array[Byte]](bytes)` for Avro data.

where

> `T`: The type of the Avro record (e.g. a `Tweet`) based on the underlying Avro schema being used.  Must be a subclass of Avro's `SpecificRecordBase`.

The key part of the code is (I collapsed the code into this snippet):

```
// With T <: SpecificRecordBase

implicit val specificAvroBinaryInjection: Injection[T, Array[Byte]] =
SpecificAvroCodecs.toBinary[T]

val bytes: Array[Byte] = ...; // the Avro-encoded data
val decodeTry: Try[T] = Injection.invert(bytes)
decodeTry match {
  case Success(pojo) =>
    System.out.println("Binary data decoded into pojo: " + pojo)
  case Failure(e) => log.error("Could not decode binary data: " + Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(e))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
            Schema schema = parser.parse(new File("/Users/.../schema.avsc"));
            Injection<Command, byte[]> objectInjection = SpecificAvroCodecs.toBinary(schema);
            byte[] bytes = objectInjection.apply(c);
```

Comment: Am I correct to assume that the schema will still be part of the object itself here? As there is a method .getSchema() available on the (generic)record. This to me seems to defeat the whole purpose of having a separate schema